# ¿Cómo agrego event listener a muchos elementos indicandolos con indices?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Soy principiante y estoy comenzando a realizar mis primeros proyectos, en este caso estoy haciendo un "whac a mole" el tipico juego de pegarle al topo pero en este caso con tematica de mario bross.

[image: Imagen del whac a mole]

Primero selecciono todas las imagenes de la siguiente manera, son todas etiquetas img dentro de un div con id "game"

```html
const game=document.getElementById("game")
const imagenes=game.children
```

Tengo 9 imágenes a las cuales les quiero agregar un event listener a cada una, la funcion que le paso al event listener es la siguiente:

```js
function cambia(index){
  if(imagenes[index].src.match("corte")){
    imagenes[index].src="./tuberiahongo.png"
    console.log("Se corrio el if")
  }
  else{
    imagenes[index].src="./tuberia_corte.png"
    console.log("Se corrio el else")
  }
}
```

"tuberia_corte" y "tuberiahongo" son entre las imagenes que quiero alternar.

Cuando le agrego a una imagen a mano el event listener de esta manera si funciona:

```
imagenes[0].addEventListener("click",()=>cambia(0))
```

Pero luego quiero agregarles a todas con un for y no funciona:

```js
for(i=0;i<imagenes.length;i++){
  imagenes[i].addEventListener("click",()=>cambia(i))
}
```

Es mi primera consulta y espero que haya sido clara, desde ya gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas el codigo completo para entender un poco mas tu logica; E Intenta hacer un `querySelectorAll()` de todas las imágenes, después solo recórrelas con un `forEach();`

Comment: creo que debes tener un addEventListener para cada elemento por separado, en tu for lo que estas haciendo es que solo le estas asignado el addEventListener a la ultima imagen que se itera en tu for

Comment: esta respuesta te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/a/38860151/16538357 básicamente hace lo mismo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pongo mi respuesta, en base a mi comentario, esto es con un `forEach();`, espero te sirva o te guie si quieres cambiar un poco la logica.

```js
imagenes = document.querySelectorAll('img');

imagenes.forEach( imagen => {

  imagen.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

    const id = imagen.getAttribute('id');

    cambia( id );

  });
});

const cambia = ( id ) => {
  /**
   * aca recibes el id de la imagen que clickaste
   */

  alert(`clickaste la imagen ${id}`);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <style>
    img{
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="game">
      <img id="1" src="" alt="">
      <img id="2" src="" alt="">
      <img id="3" src="" alt="">
      <img id="4" src="" alt="">
      <img id="5" src="" alt="">
      <img id="6" src="" alt="">
      <img id="7" src="" alt="">
      <img id="8" src="" alt="">
      <img id="9" src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un "pequeño problema" con el ciclo:

```
for(i=0;i<imagenes.length;i++){
    imagenes[i].addEventListener("click",()=>cambia(i))
}
```

Al usar simplemente `i = 0`, javascript automáticamente declara la variable con alcance global (`var i = 0`), de forma que al ejecutar `cambia(i)` siempre tendrá el valor de la última iteración del ciclo.

La solución es limitar el alcance de la variable, declarándola con [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

```
for(let i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++){
    imagenes[i].addEventListener("click", () => cambia(i));
}
```

De esta forma, es como crear una variable independiente para cada iteración del ciclo y cada una puede mantener el valor dentro de la función del evento.

Answer (score 0):

Estas seguro que no tienes elementos intermedios entre "game" y los cubos?

Asi te debería funciona si todo es correcto:

```js
const cubos = document.getElementById("game").children;

for(let i=0; i<cubos.length; i++) {
  cubos[i].addEventListener("click", () => alert(`Click en el cubo ${i+1}`))
}
```

```css
.cubo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div class="cubo">1</div>
  <div class="cubo">2</div>
  <div class="cubo">3</div>
  <div class="cubo">4</div>
  <div class="cubo">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenté lo siguiente y funcionó: Utilizé un querySelectorAll para obtener el array de imagenes y luego con un forEach funcionó.

```js
const game=document.getElementById("game")
const imagenes=game.querySelectorAll(".img")
```

Luego el forEach:

```js
imagenes.forEach((imagen)=>imagen.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  
  if(imagen.src.match("corte")){
    imagen.src="./tuberiahongo.png"
  }
  else{
    imagen.src="./tuberia_corte.png"
  }




}))
```

Ahora cada vez que apreto una imagen la se alterna entre "tuberia_corte" y "tuberiahongo".

Me fué muy útil la respuesta de Triby acerca de los lazos for en javascript (soy nuevo en este lenguaje, aprendí lo básico en python)

Muchas gracias.